# HazelcastSerializationException for an IMap InternalKey - how to debug or log

Tags: exception, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, jcache

We are using a Class that implements `Cache<K, V>`. The cached stored in a Hazelcast `IMap<InternalKey<K, C>, V>`. There's a "remove" logic that removes by an `InternalKey` of `<String, String>`.

`K`, `C` and `V` are all Strings.

```
public class HazelcastMapJCacheAdapter<K, C, V> implements Cache<K, V> {
    private IMap<InternalKey<K, C>, V> cachedData;

    public void removeEntriesByKeyAndContext(BiPredicate<K, C> removeCondition) {
        Predicate<InternalKey<K, C>, V> predicate = (Predicate<InternalKey<K, C>, V> & Serializable)
            mapEntry -> (removeCondition.test(mapEntry.getKey().getOriginalKey(), mapEntry.getKey().getContext()));
        cachedData.removeAll(predicate);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a `HazelcastSerializationException` which I can't understand. What can go wrong with String serialisation? How can I properly log this scenario in order to get more data (the argument I have at hand is a Predicate which is a function interface...)? I fail to reproduce this scenario on my development environment, so debugging it is a problem.

Thanks

```
2020-03-23 02:07:34 WARN | [10.212.179.245]:5701 [MyApp] [3.12.5] Error while logging processing event
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:82) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:124) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundOperationHandler.send(OutboundOperationHandler.java:56) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeRemote(Invocation.java:656) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:631) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:592) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:256) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:61) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvokeOnPartitions.invokeOnAllPartitions(InvokeOnPartitions.java:121) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvokeOnPartitions.invokeAsync(InvokeOnPartitions.java:99) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvokeOnPartitions.invoke(InvokeOnPartitions.java:88) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.invokeOnAllPartitions(OperationServiceImpl.java:385) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.removeAllInternal(MapProxySupport.java:618) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.NearCachedMapProxyImpl.removeAllInternal(NearCachedMapProxyImpl.java:330) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.removeAll(MapProxyImpl.java:285) ~[hazelcast-3.12.5.jar:3.12.5]
    at com.myapp.cache.impl.HazelcastMapJCacheAdapter.removeEntriesByKeyAndContext(HazelcastMapJCacheAdapter.java:578) ~[myapp-distributed-cache-impl.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary of requirements for `removeAll` (and any other kind of server-side processing like `executeOnKey` etc):

- Key and value must be serializable and their classes must be available on server classpath
- `Predicate` (or `EntryProcessor` etc) must be serializable and available on server classpath

My guess is that in your case the `BiPredicate<K, C> removeCondition` is not serializable; however it has to be serialized as part of the lambda you pass to `removeAll`. For example consider this code:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        remove((x, y) -> true);
    }

    private static void remove(BiPredicate<String, String> predicate) {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        // put 100 items in the map
        IMap<String, String> map = hz.getMap("map");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            map.put("" + i, "" + i);
        }

        map.removeAll((Predicate<String, String> & Serializable)
                entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

        // now size is 0
        System.out.println("Map size after removeAll " + map.size());
    }
}
```

The above code will be executed without any issues. The moment you add another `HazelcastInstance` in the cluster (just add `Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()` in `remove` method body), the `Predicate` instance must be serialized and sent over the network between the 2 cluster members. This fails because the `predicate` argument is not `Serializable` but it is part of the lambda `Predicate` passed as argument to `removeAll`. The solution is to make sure everything referenced in your lambda is serializable. So in the above example the fix is to update `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    remove((BiPredicate<String, String> & Serializable) (x, y) -> true);
}
```

On a general note, exercise caution when using lambdas because it is easy to accidentally capture outer class fields and in that case you will need to address serializability of containing class and your lambda's serialized form size will balloon unexpectedly. Quoting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#serialization "You can serialize a lambda expression if its target type and its captured arguments are serializable. However, like inner classes, the serialization of lambda expressions is strongly discouraged."

Comment: Indeed the problem turned out to to the input argument predicate, that was not marked as Serializable. So our predicate was composed out of 2 'inner' predicates, but one was not Serializable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set class definition of InternalKey on Server’s classpath as Entries are deserialized for predicates.

Slightly out of context, you can also try setting `in-memory-format` to OBJECT for performance gains in predicate execution.